# Speedup SQL Database Shrinking Process

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to shrink and backup a database every week which is about 100+ GB of size.

Normally it takes 2-3 hours to shrink. This is quite frustrating especially when management wants this database to be deployed quickly.

My question is

1-Is there some way to shrink a huge database quickly.
2-Instead of shrinking, if I do a backup with shrink option enabled, does it do the same, like removing unnecessary pages.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to shrink at all?

Comment: Why do you shrink the database? When the released space is used later again, you may run into serious fragmentation problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: no, in generally you do not shrink "real" databases (of size). specially given that SQL Server backup will not back up pages in the database not used, so a backup of an empty 1000gb database is VERY small, it makes no sense to shrink. How you think people do real backups of IMPORTANT stuff (where you run a delta backup like every 15 minutes)? Generally do not use autogrow, do not use shrink on anything that has a large size.

2: moot as per 1. Do not shrink.

Why do you think you need to shrink the database in the first place? Btw., 100gb is quite small - things get runny once you hit 1000gb and larger.

Comment: Actually I need to ftp this database, that's the reason I want to shrink as much as possible.

Comment: @MuhammadSharjeelAhsan Sorry, that is a non reason at all. Take backup, compressed, ship it. No need to shrink the database.